# promql metric for memory usage of containers in kubernetes cluster

Tags: grafana, promql, google-cloud-monitoring

I want to filter the results as per containers but the below mentioned queries are not returning container labels.

container_memory_usage_bytes / container_memory_working_set_bytes

Comment: They are not supposed to return labels, you will have to enrich the query yourself

Comment: how can i do that...any hints?